# How to update a version number in plist of xcode through jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins

I would like to update my build numbers in plist file with SVNrevisionnumber_Sandbox or SVNrevisionnumber_Production for my ios app based on configuration through shell script as build step in jenkins .

Comment: What approach have you tried so far? What "configuration" do you mean?

Comment: I am following execute shell part in build step by using Plistbuddy , am able to set the revision number, but I wants to set as SVNrevisionnumber_Production or SVNrevisionnumber_Sandbox , here configuration means either  Production or Sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Setup "Execute Shell" build step
- Use **[PlistBuddy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html)** command line to manipulate the plist file
- It's recommended to supply absolute (not relative) paths to plist file and the executable

Comment: How could we set  SVNrevisionnumber_Production or SVNrevisionnumber_Sandbox into plist file , here am able to set SVNrevisionnumber but I wants to insert which configuration it is like sandbox/production

Comment: You can use `${SVN_REVISION_1}_Production`, change `1` to `2` and so on, for each SVN checkout module (if configured through Jenkins). You can use that variable in your "Execute Shell" step